# Node.js/Mongojs nested db callbacks return

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, restify

I am implementing a restify middleware for session authentication. The function contains nested asynchronous db calls: db.sessions.remove() within the callback of db.sessions.findOne().

The 'return' statements are confusing me because I'm not sure if I am returning next() or next(err) from the callback back to verifyUserSession(), or is it just returning from verifyUserSessions? Am I doing this right?

```
function verifyUserSession(req, res, next) {


if (req.headers.sessionKey) 
{
    db.sessions.findOne(req.headers.sessionKey, function(err, session) {

        if (err) 
        {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!session) 
        {
            return next(new Error({'message': 'Session does not exist'}));
        }

        if ((new Date().getTime() - session.timestamp.getTime())/86400000 > 60)
        {
            db.sessions.remove({sessionKey: req.headers.sessionKey}, function(err){
                if (err) 
                {
                    return next(err);
                }
                return next(new Error({'message': 'Session expired'}));
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // session ok
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the callbacks just right.

`return` is used only to return from the current callback. When you call `return next(...)` you invoke the callback function and return the value it returns. Returns are often needed only to make sure you don't invoke a callback twice.

Note that you need to make sure every possible branch in your function will invoke the callback, otherwise your program will never proceed from `verifyUserSession`. In the code example you gave this happens two cases: 1) if session is ok, 2) if `req.headers.sessionKey` is not set. You should add callbacks for these branches as well.

Answer (score 1):

Return statements in asynchronous coding are used **only** because they interrupt further execution of the block code. Basically this:

```
db.sessions.remove({sessionKey: req.headers.sessionKey}, function(err){
    if (err) 
    {
        return next(err);
    }
    return next(new Error({'message': 'Session expired'}));
});
```

is equivalent to:

```
db.sessions.remove({sessionKey: req.headers.sessionKey}, function(err){
    if (err) 
    {
        next(err);
        return;
    }
    next(new Error({'message': 'Session expired'}));
    return;
});
```

Note that last return is unnecessary.